# Sharepoint 2013 worflow - wait for field change

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

I have a basic workflow I'm trying to build (my first..)

The flow is:

1. List item created
2. Group owner is emailed
3. Wait until group owner changes the 'assigned to' field
4. Change item status

The problem I have is that I can't see how to get the workflow to wait for the assigned to field to be changed before proceeding with the workflow. There will be around 10 different options for that field so I don't want to test for each option and the 2013 workflows don't let me test for not null..

I'm sure there is an obvious solution but I've had no luck in google!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `Assigned To` value in a workflow variable first and then use the action `wait for` to **not equal** to workflow:variable. Example

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does that answer apply to Sharepoint 2013 workflows? The Wait option in 2013 doesn't allow for 'not equal' in the comparison.

Comment: Yes, it is for SharePoint 2013 on-premises workflows.